# How do I prove Binet's Formula?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

My initial prompt is as follows:

> For $F_{0}=1$, $F_{1}=1$, and for $n\geq 1$, $F_{n+1}=F_{n}+F_{n-1}$.
>   Prove for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$:
>
> $$F_{n-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n\right)$$

Which, to my understanding, is Binet's Formula.

I came up with a proof strategy similar to that described [here](http://library.thinkquest.org/27890/applications2p.html). But as you can see, it is considering the case of $F_n$, not $F_{n-1}$.

So, my question is: does the same strategy hold for $F_{n-1}$? If not, how is it different?

Comment: @Whoever is voting to close: Why?  This is a perfectly understandable question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem that you’ve been given uses a less-standard indexing of the Fibonacci numbers. The usual definition has initial values $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$; your $F_n$ is the usual $F_{n+1}$, and the usual $F_n$ is your $F_{n-1}$. Thus, where your link has $$\varphi^a=F(a)\varphi+F(a-1)\;,$$ you’ll need to write $$\varphi^a=F_{a-1}\varphi+F_{a-2}\;.$$ As a quick check, when $a=2$ that gives you $\varphi^2=F_1\varphi+F_0=\varphi+1$, which you can see from the link is correct.

(I’m assuming here that your proof really does follow pretty much the pattern in the link. You can also just do a straight induction: the induction step is the same whichever indexing you use.)

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to tell without reading your proof, but induction (as a principle) will work regardless of whether you consider $n$ or $n-1$.  The only difference is the indexing of the base case, but with the shift $n \mapsto n-1$ you needn't worry about introducing a "gap" at all.