# Prove by induction (Fibonacci) $F_n=\frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n}{\sqrt5}$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

Can someone advise on proving the following by induction. I'm assuming strong induction should be used here?

Here $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number. Prove that

$$F_n=\frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n}{\sqrt5}$$

Comment: It's sort of strong induction; you need to know $F_{n-1}$ and $F_{n-2}$ both satisfy the desired equality in order to conclude that $F_n$ does. The remaining values are irrelevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove this formula for the Fibonacci Sequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65011/prove-this-formula-for-the-fibonacci-sequence)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, go with induction.

First, check the base case $$F_1=1$$ That should be easy.

For the inductive step, consider, on the one hand:

**(1)** $$F_{n+1}= F_n+F_{n-1}$$

Then, write what you need to prove, to have it as a guidance of what you need to get to. That is:

$$F_{n+1}=\frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^{n+1}}{\sqrt5}$$

Use **(1)** and your hypothesis and write

$$F_{n+1}= \frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n}{\sqrt5} + $$ $$\frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^{n-1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^{n-1}}{\sqrt5}$$

this translates to

$$= {\frac {1} {\sqrt5}}[{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{2}{1+\sqrt 5}\right)}-{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{2}{1-\sqrt 5}\right)}]$$

---

To finish, note that **(a)** $${\left(1+\frac{2}{1+\sqrt 5}\right)}{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{1-\sqrt 5}\right)}={\frac {1+\sqrt 5}{2}}$$
and **(b)**
$${\left(1+\frac{2}{1-\sqrt 5}\right)}{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{1+\sqrt 5}\right)}={\frac {1-\sqrt 5}{2}}$$

which is exactly what you need to end the proof.

Comment: Would you need to include $F_0$ as well as $F_1$ in the basis step?

Comment: @ClownInTheMoon Yes, you would. Sorry I didn't write it.

Comment: @ClownInTheMoon Sure. You take the common factor $${\frac {1} {\sqrt5}}$$  and sort the terms out. Then, common factor again with  $$\phi^n$$ and $$\psi^n$$

Comment: $=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\phi^n-\psi^n+\phi^{n-1}-\psi^{n-1})\\
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\phi^n-\psi^n+\phi^n\phi^{-1}-\psi^n\psi^{-1})\\
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\phi^n+\phi^n\phi^{-1}-\psi^n-\psi^n\psi^{-1})\\
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}[\phi^n(1+\phi^{-1})-\psi^n(1+\psi^{-1})]$

Comment: @ClownInTheMoon Yup.

Answer (score 5):

$$F_n=\frac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt5}$$

Then the recurrence relation can be written

$$F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}-F_n=\frac{\phi^2\phi^n-\psi^2\psi^n}{\sqrt5}-\frac{\phi\phi^n-\psi\psi^n}{\sqrt5}-\frac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt5}=0.$$

The identify holds if

$$\phi^2-\phi-1=\psi^2-\psi-1=0,$$ which is precisely the case.

The base cases for $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$ are easy to check.

Answer (score 1):

It's enough for your induction to work to know that the previous two satisfy this equality. So the induction would work like this:

1) Base. Check that $ F_0, F_1 $ satisfy the equality

2) Step. Assume that $ F_{n-2}, F_{n-1} $ satisfy the equality and derive $ F_n $ for $ n > 1 $

More details can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/484818/122418)